# Cannot load module in Webpack where the module name contains a dot

Tags: webpack, parallel-coordinates

I would like to use d3.parcoords.js with webpack. I have installed d3.parcoords.js through npm but when I do a

```
require('d3.parcoords.js')
```

I get the error message 'Cannot resolve d3.parcoords.js'. 
I have the following in my web.config.js:

```
resolve:{
    modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", "bower_components"]
}
```

I tried

```
require('d3.parcoords.js/d3.parcoords.js')
```

and it seems to load the d3.parcoords.js file but not the dependencies residing under the d3.parcoords.js/src folder.

I suspect it has to do with the dot in the module name but I don't know how to have a work around.

I'd appreciate any insights, thoughts.

Thanks